# fixing and combining drains in duplex

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

I recently bought a home in need of repair. It's a 2 unit property.

The kitchens were both draining into a broken tee that was causing some water damage. It is currently a mess of poorly glued PVC + abs and no-hub couplers.

We are having the roof replaced next week so if any of the venting should be changed, now is the time.

I'm mainly trying to figure out the best way to combine all these drains, and also add a drain line added to the second unit for its own washing machine.

Should the second unit have its own connection to be main drain all together? If so would I be able to tie into the existing vents?

[image: Sketch overview]

[image: Unit 1 with washer]
[Unit 1 + vent stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzEr7.jpg)

[image: Unit 2 current]

[image: Under house view to main drain]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the current layout, assuming that the trap arms aren't too long. I would just replace the sanitary tee for the laundry with a double. What specific concerns do you have? What are the trap arm lengths at the furthest traps?

Comment: Trap is about 4ft on the one side, and 5-6ft on the other. My main concern is how much potential water might be drained at once between 2 kitchen sinks and 2 washing machines for two different units.